# Energy Spectrum of pair of spin-1/2 particles with general Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, spinors

I found this problem, and so far I am stumped. I was wondering if anyone wanted to solve it with me, or help me calculate eigenvectors, or just give insight on my questions.

> *Consider a system of two spin-1/2 particles interacting through the Hamitonian
>   $$H = A(S_x^2 − S_y^2) + BS_z^2,$$ 
>   where $A$ and $B$ are constants and $S_x$, $S_y$ and $S_z$ are the three components of the total spin of the system. Find the energy spectrum and the corresponding eigenvectors.*

It's been awhile since I did QM, and I *know* you can't have simultaneous eigenvectors of more than one measurement of spin along an axis, but how does that relate to this problem where there Sx^2 and Sy^2 are in the hamiltonian? I've been trying to work out 4x4 matrices, but I can't find good eigenvectors, but even then I am confused how applying a pauli matrix (say for x or y) transforms the eigenvector to another eigenvector, which I think is another example of not being able to define simultaneous eigenvectors etc. How would one start this problem? I will break it down to S^2 and Sz terms, but there will be remaining terms, will they just not contribute to the energy spectrum? If someone much more knowledgable than me could solve this problem easily and post it, that would clarify so much to me. For now, I'll try to read Feynman's lecture on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I basically do what joshphysics has already mentioned, just in a little more detail, and in a bit more intuitive basis (which makes effectively no difference). So definitely not a slick way.

I use the basis $|m_1\rangle\otimes|m_2\rangle$, where $m_i=\pm1/2$. Keeping only the sign we denote the basis as $\{|++\rangle,|+-\rangle,|-+\rangle,|--\rangle\}$.

Now for $S_z=S_{1z}+S_{2z}$ you can check that 
$$
S_z|++\rangle=\left(\frac{\hbar}{2}+\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)|++\rangle
$$
and similarly
$$
S_z|--\rangle=\left(-\frac{\hbar}{2}-\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)|--\rangle
$$
so that you and up with the matrix
$$
S_z\rightarrow\hbar\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{array}\right]
$$

and

$$
S_z^2\rightarrow\hbar^2\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right]
$$

For $S_x$ and $S_y$ you use raising and lowering operators as josh suggested and obtain the matrix elements by acting on each state in the basis and seeing what has a non-zero dot product with the result, e.g.

$$
\begin{align}
S_y|+-\rangle=\frac{1}{2i}\left(S_+-S_-\right)|+-\rangle&=\\\frac{1}{2i}\left(S_{1+}+S_{2+}-S_{1-}-S_{2-}\right)|+-\rangle&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\hbar|++\rangle-\hbar|--\rangle\right)
\end{align}
$$

thus $\langle++|S_y|+-\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{2i}$ and $\langle--|S_y|+-\rangle=-\frac{\hbar}{2i}$. Once you do this you can get

$$
S_x\rightarrow\hbar\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\end{array}\right]
$$

and

$$
S_y\rightarrow\hbar\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&1&1&0\\-1&0&0&1\\-1&0&0&1\\0&-1&-1&0\end{array}\right]
$$

Finally the Hamiltonian looks like
$$
H=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}\hbar^2B&0&0&\hbar^2A\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\\hbar^2A&0&0&\hbar^2B\end{array}\right]
$$

Therefore $|+-\rangle$ and $|-+\rangle$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$, and you only need diagonalize $2\times2$ matrix to find that the eigenvalue $\hbar^2\left(B+A\right)$ corresponds to the eigenvector $\left(|++\rangle+|--\rangle\right)/\sqrt{2}$, and $\hbar^2\left(B-A\right)$ corresponds to the eigenvector $\left(|++\rangle-|--\rangle\right)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your detailed walkthrough. I am going to work through this later tonight and post if I have any questions.

Comment: My only question (I think) is how do you explicitly decide what column vectors represent each state? I have read before about two basis eigenvectors will have eigenvalues of zero, but then is that a justification that linear combinations of the other two states will be states of the system? Also, (h-bar taken to be unity), what is the reasoning why there is no eigenvalue (A-B)? Thank you again, I'm still working it out.

Comment: You're welcome. In principle your only constraint is to choose a ortho-normal basis; the ordering of the vectors is your free choice (I hope I understood your question correctly).

Comment: The fact that you have zero eigenvalues doesn't have much to do with the fact that you need to diagonalize the $\{|++\rangle,|--\rangle\}$ subspace. For example if you would calculate $S^2$ you would find no zero eigenvalues, but would again need to diagonalize a subspace, this time $\{|+-\rangle,|-+\rangle\}$. My reasoning for the lack of the eigenvalue $A-B$ is the lack of the symmetry of the Hamiltonian and the appropriate eigenvector. Anyhow I recommend you take a look at Shankar's Principle of Quantum Mechanics, Section 15 - Addition of Angular Momenta it might be helpful.

Comment: I will find a digital copy of that book and read that section, when you say diagonalize the subspace does that mean generate a basis that spans the subspace? I am unfamiliar with the concept of diagonalizing anything more than a matrix! Also, what is the physical meaning of $\langle--|S_y|+-\rangle=-\frac{\hbar}{2i}$ ? I thought expectation values need to have the same bra and ket eigenvector, and if they are different eigenvectors that represents a transition probability? I definitely have a lot of reading to do tonight! Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to diagonalizing a $2\times2$ matrix. You are right, expectation values need the same bras and kets, this is just an ordinary matrix element. It means that if you act with $S_y$ on the state  $|+-\rangle$ it will rotate it in the Hilbert space, such that one of it's components will lie along the $|--\rangle$ direction (again in Hiblert, not real space). If you were to think of $S_y$ as a perturbation, than the transition probability would depend on this matrix element. Best regards, and good luck!

Comment: Hi again, I have another question about the linear combination chosen at the end of your derivation. We have $\left(|++\rangle-|--\rangle\right)/\sqrt{2}$, why was this chosen over $\left(|--\rangle-|++\rangle\right)/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Hi, the choice was arbitrary. It could have equally well been $\left(|--\rangle-|++\rangle\right)/\sqrt{2}$; the minus sign makes no physical difference. In fact you could multiply it with $e^{i\phi}$, where $\phi$ is arbitrary, and still end up with the same physical state.

Comment: Oh, I totally see it now! thanks! I just calculated the eigenvalue of $(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\\1\end{array})$ and see that now. Thanks for the clarification, really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me at this point that there is a tricky way to do this problem, but here is a systematic way that would work for any hamiltonian written in terms of the components of the total spin operator.

As you have indicated, the Hamiltonian acts on a $4$-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, so it can be written as a $4$-by-$4$ matrix in a given basis.  The eigenvalues of the matrix don't depend on the basis you choose, so provided you can determine the matrix representation of $H$ in some basis, you can just find the eigenvalues of this matrix, and you'll be done.

Is there a convenient basis to choose?  Well, I'd say that the basis $|s, m\rangle$ consisting of simultaneous eigenvectors of $\mathbf S^2$ and $S_z$, the total spin squared and total $z$-component of spin operators, is best because we'll easily be able to compute the matrix elements of the Hamiltonian in this basis as you'll see in a moment;
$$
  \mathbf S^2|s,m\rangle = \hbar^2s(s+1)|s,m\rangle, \qquad S_z |s,m\rangle = \hbar m|s,m\rangle
$$
Since the system consists of two spin-$1/2$ particles, this basis contains three spin-$1$ states and one spin-$0$ state; $\{|1,1\rangle,|1,0\rangle, |1,-1\rangle, |0,0\rangle\}$ .  These are the so-called triplet and singlet states that arise from appropriately "adding" the two spins quantum mechanically.

Now, of course the $S_z^2$ term is particularly easy to deal with in this basis, in fact, the matrix representation of $S_z^2$ in this basis is diagonal.  The trick is to therefore compute the matrix representation of $S_x^2 - S_y^2$ in this basis.  This can be done systematically using raising and lowering operators.  Recall that
$$
  S_+ =S_x + iS_y, \qquad S_- = S_x - iS_y
$$
so that
$$
  S_x = \frac{1}{2}(S_+ + S_-), \qquad S_y = \frac{1}{2i}(S_+ - S_-) 
$$
and therefore for example
$$
  S_x^2 = \frac{1}{4}(S_+^2 + 2S_+S_- + S_-^2)
$$
and similarly for $S_y^2$.  Now you just need to use these expressions to determine the matrix representation of the Hamiltonian in this basis and find its eigenvalues.

I strongly suspect that there is a slicker way of doing this problem, but it's just not coming to me at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I think what was holding me back from explicitly writing 4x4 matrices is choosing an eigenvector basis that makes sense. For isntance how do you decide what column matrix |+-> should be represented by?

Comment: @walczyk If you are only looking for the spectrum of this Hamiltonian, then you don't need the column matrix representation of any vector to do this since you only need the matrix representation of the Hamiltonian in the given basis whose entries can be computed (for the basis I refer to) as $\langle m,s|H|m',s'\rangle$.  As a secondary issue, however, if you are given any vector $|\psi\rangle$ in the Hilbert space, then its column vector representation in the basis I gave would just have as entries the four numbers $\langle m,s|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Sorry the last symbol in that response should have been written as $\langle s, m|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: you said $\langle s,m | \psi \rangle$ is represented by four numbers? s would be 1 in this case, and m would be -1, 0, or 1 no? And then the other two numbers would basically be a spinor ? Sorry, I know that an explicit column vector is unncessary, but I guess I like the explicit nature of matrix algebra, so I am having trouble giving up explicit eigenvectors in the derivation.

Comment: Given two spin-$1/2$ particles, the possible combinations of $(s, m)$, are $(1,1),(1,0),(1,-1),(0,0)$; there are four of them.  This gives four possible values for the inner product $\langle s,m|\psi\rangle$, and these four numbers are the entries of $|\psi\rangle$ in the $|s,m\rangle$ basis.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now. Those four eigenstates form a basis, and $|\psi \rangle$ would be a linear combination of these four states, with coefficients whose squares add up to one.

Comment: Precisely.  One would have $|\psi\rangle = \sum c_{s,m}|s,m\rangle$ and orthonormality of the states $|s,m\rangle$ then gives $c_{s,m} = \langle s,m|\psi\rangle$, and these coefficients are precisely the entries of the matrix representation of $|\psi\rangle$ in the $|s,m\rangle $ basis.

Answer (score 1):

If one is able to have an explicit 4 * 4 matrix for the hamiltonian, the work to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors is a basic math problem. So I will suppose you know that.

I will answer to how get this hamiltonian matrix.

1) a basis, for the 2-spin state is $|0>\otimes|0>, ~|0>\otimes|1>, ~|1>\otimes|0>, ~|1>\otimes|1>$

2) The meaning of $S_i$ is in fact $S_i = ((s_1)_i \otimes \mathbb{Id_2} + \mathbb{Id_1} \otimes (s_2)_i)$,

where $(s_1)_i$ is a  $2 * 2$ matrix (spin operator) acting on the first particle, and $(s_2)_i$ is a $2 * 2$ matrix (spin operator) acting on the second particle, and where $\mathbb{Id_1}$ and $\mathbb{Id_2}$ are $2 * 2$ matrix acting respectively on particules #1 and #2.

Note, then you have $(s_1)_i = (s_2)_i = \frac{1}{2} \sigma_i$, where  $\sigma_i$ is the Pauli matrice.

Note, then, that you have  $((s_1)_i)^2 = ((s_2)_i)^2 = \frac{1}{4} \mathbb{Id}$

3) Now, you can simplify the hamiltonian : $H = A(S_x^2 − S_y^2) + BS_z^2,$

For instance $S_x^2 = ((s_1)_x \otimes \mathbb{Id_2} + \mathbb{Id_1} \otimes (s_2)_x)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Id_1} \otimes \mathbb{Id_2} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x$.

So, you will have :

$H =\frac{B}{2}  \mathbb{Id} + \frac{1}{2} (A(\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x - \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y) + B \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z)$

Here $\mathbb{Id} = \mathbb{Id_1} \otimes \mathbb{Id_2}$ is the $4*4$  identity matrix.

4) To get the hamiltonian matrix, now just apply H to the basic vectors, for instance :

$$H ~(|0>\otimes|0>) = \frac{B}{2} |0>\otimes|0> + \frac{1}{2}(A(|1>\otimes|1> - i^2 |1>\otimes|1>) 
+ B|0>\otimes|0>)$$

That is : $$H ~(|0>\otimes|0>) = B|0>\otimes|0> + A |1>\otimes|1>$$

By doing the same thing with the other basis vectors, you will get the full  $4*4$ hamiltonian matrix.

Note: if you understand the notation $|0>\otimes|0>$, you can use the notation $|0>|0>$ which is simpler.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I need to use tensor products more frequently to get a better understanding of it. I will work through this tonight.

Comment: There is no difficulty with the tensorial product.The basic idea,  when you have a operator $A \otimes B$ acting on a state $|a> \otimes |b>$, the  result is :$A|a> \otimes B|b>$. And you may consider the basis $|0>\otimes|0>, ~|0>\otimes|1>, ~|1>\otimes|0>, ~|1>\otimes|1>$ like any standard orthonormal basis.

Comment: If you make an operator product, it gives simply $(A \otimes  B) * (C \otimes  D) = (AC \otimes  BD) $

Comment: Interesting. The issue I have with representing tensor products with matrices is how elements that refer to particle #1 are distinguished from the elements that refer to particle #2. Is it implicit in the design of the matrix? That the 4x4 identity matrix, while it looks like a standard identity matrix, actually represents two 2x2 identity matrices. I think I need to practice going from tensor products to explicit matrix representations and seeing how the elements stay separated. The tensor product in this case would be a kronecker product (direct product) right?

Comment: The formalism and rules I gave you, is precisely the way to not consider in detail how the tensorial matrix is built, and so, it is simpler. However, If you want to manipulate matrix directly, let me give you an example :

For instance suppose a $2*2$ matrix $A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}a_{11} &a_{12}\\\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\end{array}\right]$, and a $2*2$ matrix $B$. 

What is $A \otimes B$?

It is simply the $4*4$ matrix:
 $\left[\begin{array}{cccc}a_{11} B&a_{12}B\\\\a_{21}B&a_{22}B&\end{array}\right]$

Comment: And, for the basis, if you take a vector basis $u_0,u_1$ for $A$ and  a vector basis $v_0,v_1$ for $B$, the vector basis for $A \otimes B$ is $u_0 \otimes v_0, u_0 \otimes v_1,u_1 \otimes v_0,u_1 \otimes v_1$, and you may call this basis $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ if you want.

Comment: I had a question about your Step 4. How do you construct the 4x4 matrix? It seems like you get 4 different 2x2 matrices, one for each basis eigenvector? And you have to make linear combinations yadda yadda, because two of the base vectors have null eigenvalues. How does one construct the 4x4 matrix at this step explicitly? I guess that is one conceptual gap I am having, I understand how you made a 4x4 from the direct product of two 2x2 matrices, but step form is four separate 2x2 matrices, or maybe not. Are they 4x1 column vectors, or 2x2 matrices?

Comment: The basis vectors $|00>,|01>,|10>,|11>$ is a vector basis. So you could call them $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ if you want. Now writing $H ~(|0>|0>) = B|0>|0> + A |1>|1>$, is the same thing as saying that $H ~ \vec w_1 = B \vec w_1 + A \vec w_4$, that is  $H_{11} = B$, and $H_{41} = A$. The general formula is then $H \vec w_j = \sum H_{ij} \vec w_i$. So you easily get the  H matrix coefficients.

Comment: Ah, okay. Does that mean the vector basis cannot be 2x2 matrices? I see now how H is constructed, I was just wondering if the basis is forced to be 4x1 column matrices.

Comment: Oops I missed the window to edit my last comment. Would it be possible to directly calculate the hamiltonian from step 3 where you have defined it with products of pauli matrices? $H =\frac{B}{2}  \mathbb{Id} + \frac{1}{2} (A(\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x - \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y) + B \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z)$

Comment: Since two of the basis states has a zero eigenvalue, how does one choose how to construct the linear combinations of the remaining two vectors? I think this is an elementary question on the singlet/triplet state, I guess I don't see the part in the mathematics that forces one to choose the linear combinations $\left(|++\rangle+|--\rangle\right)/\sqrt{2}$ and $\left(|++\rangle-|--\rangle\right)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: a) No, the vectors basis are vectors, not $2*2$ matrix.   b) No, If you want to have explicitely the hamiltonian matrix, you have to use step 4. c) Trusting "mgphys", the non-null part of the hamiltonian is simply  $\left[\begin{array}{cccc}B &A\\\\A&B&\end{array}\right]$, with the basis vector $|00>,|11>$ (in my notations). So you  have to do the basic math job to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors (read a math textbook if you don't know). In this case, the eigenvectors are $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(|00> + |11>)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(|00> - |11>)$   with eigenvalues $B+A$ and $B-A$.

Comment: Would there be four eigenvectors and only two eigenvalues? In addition to the two you mentioned wouldn't the basis vectors also be eigenvectors with eigenvalues B+A ? $|++\rangle$, $|--\rangle$, $\left(|++\rangle+|--\rangle\right)/\sqrt{2}$, and $\left(|++\rangle-|--\rangle\right)/\sqrt{2}$, with eigenvalues B+A, B+A, B+A and B-A? I see that you turned the 4s4 matrix into a 2x2 matrix, but physically does that mean we cannot measure pure states only those two linear combinations?

Comment: Oh dear, I just looked again and realize that those first two basis vectors can't be eigenvectors, if you apply one to H you don't get a multiple of that vector back, you'll get one of the linear combinations. I need to write this on paper before bugging you with useless questions. There are only two eigenstates, thank you!

Comment: Sorry.No. You have 4 eigenvectors (because it is an $4*4$ hermitian matrix), and you have 3 eigenvalues. Maybe I was explaining things too fast. In fact I have simplyfied the $4*4$ matrix $H=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}B&0&0&A\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\A&0&0&B\end{array}\right]$ into a $2*2$ because, if you change the order of the vector basis and take $|00>,|11>,|01>,|10>$ as a new order for the vector basis, you will  get $H=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}B&A&0&0\\A&B&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$ . It is easy to see that   $|01>,|10>$ are obvious eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: So the 3 eigenvalues are $B+A,B-A,0$, and you have $4$ eigenvectors.

Comment: Ah I see that clearly now thank you. I'm not sure what you mean by order of the vector basis however, I get that you swap the second and fourth column/row, then the second and fourth row/column. It's all dependent on how one defines the base vectors. For the degeneracy, is there anything you'd do to further define those states? Since they're degenerate, is the physical state a linear combination of both of those eigenvectors with 0 eigenvalue?

Comment: Walczyk,I suggest that you read a math book on the basics of linear algebra, matrix, diagonalization, eigenvalues, eigenvectors. So, this would be my last comment in this post: Each linear combination of the 2 eigenvectors $|01>,|10>$ is also an eigenvector with the eigenvalue 0.